# Is it possible to transfer multiple materials in one go between 2 meshes?

Tags: mesh, uv

new to Blender, will try to explain my complex problem quickly.

So, I extracted a low poly character from a game, just to be able to improve it and render it with cycles.

The extract is in .obj, when it imports in Blender, I have already basic nodes setup that I need to modify for it to look good in cycles. The thing is, the mesh is separated in different parts (head, torso, feet, hands...etc) that all have separate textures, more or less seamless.

So I set up all the nodes for these parts, and when I'm happy with it, I select all parts, go to edit mode, click mesh-->Clean-up-->Merge by distance (if I don't do it separation between parts is visible) then go back to object mode and CTRL+J to join. Then I apply a subdivision surface modifier, my character looks better and the texture looks as it should. Fine.

So what is the problem ? Well, the problem is I want to extract the same character in different poses from the game. When I do that, I have to manually redo what I explained above. I can copy/paste nodes from the first character, which saves some time, but I wanted to know if there was a way to go even faster (there's a lot of poses).

What I imagine is delete all materials from character 2 (or simply import the .obj without the .mtl file), join it as above, apply same amount of subdivision surface. And then copy in one go all the material info from 1st character joined and subdivided and past to character 2.

I tried already some stuff with append and also with vertex group specials in material pannel, but either because I'm a newb or maybe it's just impossible, I didn't manage to make it work.

Also, maybe the UV (which is either automatically generated by Blender or at least merged from the imported UV of each part when character is joined) is different because character is the same but in another pose ?

Another info : it seems the CleanUp-->Merge by distance + join, doesn't produce a mesh with the same number of vertices, faces, whatever you call it. Even tho only the pose change, not the character.

More info : each skin part of the character has 4 textures (diffuse, norm, spec, subsurf). 
I only joined the skin parts, not ohter parts like hair, eyes teeth, clothes etc.

Sorry for the length of this question, I tend to think what I'm asking is not possible, but I can't be sure since I started Blender 2 weeks ago (made a nice donut :D )

Thanks in advance whoever manages to read this all and reply.